# how to calculate the amount rectangles can you get out of a bigger rectangle

Tags: logic, rectangles

I am looking to make a program to calculate how many rectangles you can get out of a bigger rectangle.
I want both the size of the big rectangle and the smaller ones to be adjustable.

But while thinking about it i ran into a problem: 
You can`t just calculate the surface of the 2 and just divide them. 
because for certain lengths you get a piece left which is technically the same size but not the same shape.

Is there a mathematical way to approach this? or is this not doable in any logical way and do i need to make a program which makes 1 rectangle at a time and looks at every possible position and rotation?

Comment: Nice question! As one approach, perhaps you don't need to look at every possible position and rotation for each rectangle one at a time. If I told you to cut 2x3 rectangles out of a large 15x28 rectangle, how would you naturally cut them out? It should seem like it's close to best possible.

Comment: How far are you willing to go to make the "largest possible" number of small rectangles? E.g., is it allowed to align some of the small rectangles horizontally and others vertically?

Comment: @Christian Blatter Yes definitely, as long as all the smaller ones are all the same shape and size

Comment: How about aligning them at _arbitrary_ angles? For example, you may cut a rectangle $14\times1$ out of $11\times11$, but it must be aligned neither vertically nor horizontally.

Comment: This is known to be a notoriously hard problem. Check out http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51791.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems. Optimal solutions are published as we speak :)

Comment: @Aleksejs Fomins thanks for the sources, ill look into it.